# android, show arrow icon in List item

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a ListActivity declared like this

```
public class SelectSiteActivity extends ListActivity
```

Then, I have a custom adapter like this

```
public class SiteListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SimpleSiteModel>
```

and my layout looks like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/siteName"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="Site Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/siteListMoreImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/expander_ic_minimized" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How do I get the `ImageView` to be pressed all the way over to the right so they are all aligned vertically and then the `TextView` takes up the rest of the row and so they are both aligned vertically in the center?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I got it, but if you mean something like:

```
+------------+---+
|   blabla   | o |
+------------+---+
|     bla    | o |
+------------+---+
!   .......  !...!
```

then you could use `android:weight=1` for the `TextView` and `=0` for the `ImageView`, and to center the text use `android:gravity="center_horizontal"`.

Comment: It was `android:gravity="center_vertical"`, but everything else worked like a champ.

Comment: It should actually be `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` applied to the ImageView tag.